# XML Serialization - what is wrong? C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I've got the following classes:

```
               public class ObjectCollection :  List<ObjectRow>
                {

                    public Dictionary<int, ObjectRow> ObjectsAutomat { get; private set; }
                    public Dictionary<int, ObjectRow> ObjectsDelayed  { get; private set; }
                    public Dictionary<int, ObjectRow> ObjectsHandle { get; private set; }
                    public Dictionary<int, ObjectRow> ObjectsNew { get; private set; }

                    public Dictionary<string, string> Fields
                    { get; protected set; }

                    public string AddressParserFieldName { get; set; }
        // Some methods here

                }

      public class ObjectRow
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int Position { get; set; }
            public AddressParserResult AddressParserResult { get; set; }
            public ObjectStatus Status { get; set; }
            public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }

            public Item this[string fieldName]
            {
                get { /* Some code */}
                set { /* Some code */}
            }

            public Item this[int index]
            {
                get { return Items[index]; }
                set { Items[index] = value; }
            }
        }
```

And I want to be able to serialize/deserialize `ObjectCollection`. When I try to perform xml-serialization like this:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectsCollection));
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(CODE_PAGE)))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, objectsCollection);
}
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(CODE_PAGE)))
{
    var deserializedObjectsCollection = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr) as ObjectsCollection;
}
```

I don't get the object I had before. What is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: Your classes aren't even marked as XmlRoot and your properties aren't marked as XmlElement or XmlAttribute. Can you explain what you're getting as a result and why it's "not the object [you] had before?"

Comment: in addition to @RQDQ's comment - have you checked the generated XML to see if there's anything obvious that is wrong?

Comment: When I look at xml there's no `ObjectsNew` for example. I have a feeling there's something wrong with `Dictionary`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't serialize a class that implements IDictionary. Check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx).

The XmlSerializer cannot process classes implementing the IDictionary interface. This was partly due to schedule constraints and partly due to the fact that a hashtable does not have a counterpart in the XSD type system. The only solution is to implement a custom hashtable that does not implement the IDictionary interface.

Comment: What problem would there have been with regarding a Dictionary(of Foo, Bar) as an IEnumerable(of KeyValuePair(of Foo, Bar)) and either allowing the deserialization of a class which implements IEnumerable(of KeyValuePair(of Foo, Bar)) and has an add(foo,bar) method, or else convincing the Dictionary crew to add an overload for Add(KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Bar)).